# How to set up OpenMP?

Tags: c, mingw, openmp, codeblocks, tdm-gcc

I am using Codeblocks and have to run an OpenMP C program. So, I added the flag -fopenmp in Codeblocks (compiler settings) and am now getting the error of '**mingw32-g++.exe: error: libgomp.spec: No such file or directory**'

So after a bit of searching on the internet about the error, I downloaded TDM-GCC ( installed in C:\TDM-GCC-64). But still the same error is being shown on Codeblocks.

What am I doing wrong?

**Here is the build log:**

mingw32-gcc.exe   -c "D:\Language Files\MatrixMultiplication.c" -o "D:\Language Files\MatrixMultiplication.o"

mingw32-g++.exe  -o "D:\Language Files\MatrixMultiplication.exe" "D:\Language Files\MatrixMultiplication.o"  -fopenmp

mingw32-g++.exe: error: libgomp.spec: No such file or directory

Comment: so did you find `libgomp.spec` on your system? Sounds like a library while tdm-gcc sounds like a compiler and you use mingw32-gcc again, so you are not using the newly installed compiler ... I guess you would have to investigate where libgomp is supposed to come from.

Comment: @Giszmo So I put my .c file in the TDM-GCC folder and used it's command prompt. 

I wrote 'gcc -fopenmp MatrixMultiplication' and then wrote './a.out' but the second command (./a.out) is not working.

Comment: What does `gcc --version` give you? If you don't give the absolute path, it probably uses the system default `gcc` which might be mingw32-gcc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple possible causes for this: Either you did not install OpenMP with the compiler or you made a mistake in the Code::Blocks configuration. Anyways go through the following steps and you should be able to fix it. You seem to be working on Windows but I also added remarks on how to do it on Linux.

1) You will need a **compiler** that comes with OpenMP. For Windows [*download TDM-GCC*](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download) preferably the 64-bit executable (second file) and **install** it. Make sure you select **OpenMP in the component tab**: *Components > gcc (TDM current: ....) > OpenMP* (the last entry). Linux already comes with GCC so just open the command line and get yourself OpenMP by typing *sudo apt-get install libomp-dev* in the terminal.

2) You will have to **configure the Compiler in Code::Blocks** now: Go to *Settings > Compiler* under Selected Compiler select *GNU GCC Compiler* and click *Copy* and type in a convenient name for your new compiler such as *TDM-GCC Compiler*. Go to **Toolchain executables** and browse the directory for all the *Program files* (C compiler, C++ compiler, Linkers, Debugger, Resource compiler, Make) you should be able to find them in *C:\TDM-GCC-64\ ...\bin* on a Windows machine if you chose the default installation. I can't tell you the precise sub-directory as I working on a Linux machine but you should be able to find it pretty easily. Depending on your installation there might be two folders for 32- and 64-bit. For Linux this step is not necessary.

4) Then you need to set the **Linker settings**. This can be done for all projects (which I would not recommend) by doing the following steps in the aforementioned menu or for your current project by clicking *Project > Build options*. Go to *Linker settings* of the corresponding configuration (*Debug* or *Release*) and click *Add* under *Link libraries*. On a Windows machine you will need to browse a file called **libgomp-1.dll** (32-bit) or *libgomp_64-1.dll* (64-bit) which should be located in the same folder as the aforementioned *Program files*. Under Linux instead choose *-lgomp* under *Other linker options*.

3) Set the **compiler flag *-fopenmp*** (for all the projects or only the current one) by going to *Compiler settings > Other compiler options* and typing in there -fopenmp.

4) Test it with a program like the [OpenMP "Hello World"](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/samples/C/omp_hello.c).