# Openmp at Codeblocks

Tags: c, openmp, codeblocks

I will try to enable openmp at codeblocks 17.12. I added to **linker settings> other linker options> -lgomp -pthread** but when i build the program shows the errors:
*ld.exe    cannot find -lgomp
          error: ld returned 1 exit status*
What 's wrong? Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are running **Windows**. As a consequence you do not have to add *-lgomp* but instead [**libgomp-1.dll**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58546530/9938686) (32-bit) or *libgomp_64-1.dll* (64-bit).